# Delete lines in text from a special character till another special character

Tags: python

I have 500 text files in a folder, but some files have some wrong informations, I need to delete them , they are in the format of .
the text looks like:

```
< _ 
? _ 
xml _ 
version _ 
= _ 
"   _   
2-5 15-18   1.0 _   
2-6 18-19   " _ 
? _ 
> _ 
hello
world
< _ 
Paper _ 
acl-id _ 
= _ 
>
...
```

need to delete from all the part that start with < and endwith >
expected output :

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file into a string, then regex match and delete using `re.sub`. The pattern you can use is `r"<[^>]*>"` (or if you want to include the underscore, `r"<[^>]*>( _)?"`).

Comment: if I replace with `""` then it will leave me an empty line, how can I get ride of the empty line ?

Comment: You can add `\n` to the regex. If you're not sure if there will always be a newline it could be `r"<[^>]*>( _ )?\n?"`